# xbar plot: space above first bar and below last bar

Tags: pgfplots

I am creating a `pgfplot` with vertical bars using the `xbar` option. The plot has four values on the y axis and three bars per ytick.

How can I control the amount of space that is:

1. added above the first bar (e.g. AnotherOne)
2. added below the last bar (e.g. FooBar)
3. between groups of bars

I know about `y=<some value>` but that only works for (3), and using it I need to hard code a specific value, also, for plots with only one bar per group I can easily compute the `bar width` plus some padding, however when there are three bars per group that does not seem to work.

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        xmin=0,
        y=2cm,
        width  = 12cm,
        %height = 9cm,
        bar width=10pt,
        xlabel={Percentage},
        nodes near coords,
%      nodes near coords align=below, % places labels inside bars
        symbolic y coords={FooBar, FooBaz, OneMore, AnotherOne },
        ytick = data,
        enlarge x limits={value=0.5,upper},
        legend pos=south east,
        legend image post style={scale=2.1},
        legend style={row sep=8pt, column sep=8pt}
    ]
    \addplot[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=black] coordinates { (0,FooBar) (0,FooBaz) (60.0,OneMore) (40.0,AnotherOne) };
    \addplot[fill=black] coordinates { (0,FooBar) (0,FooBaz) (84.5,OneMore) (15.5,AnotherOne) };
    \addplot[pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=black] coordinates { (7,FooBar) (5,FooBaz) (62,OneMore) (18,AnotherOne) };
    \legend{Group 1, Group 2, Group 3}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to almost know the answer to 1. and 2. already. You have `enlarge x limits` in your code, similarly there is a `enlarge y limits` option. The space between the groups depends of course on the i) height of the axis, ii) the number of groups, iii) the range of the axis (so basically a combination of the number of groups and the `enlarge y limits` I suppose), iv) the number of bars in each group, v) the width of the bars, and vi) the value of `bar shift auto` (distance between bars in group).

Comment: Using `height` in combination with `enlarge y limits={value=0.2,auto}` solved it for me. The trick was to use `auto`, rather then `upper,lower` in `enlarge y limits` and combine it with `height`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, thanks to @Torbjørn for the initial idea:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        xmin=0,
        width  = 12cm,
        % reduce height to 'squeeze' bars together
        % and reduce the spacing between bars
        height = 8cm,
        bar width=10pt,
        xlabel={Percentage},
        nodes near coords,
        symbolic y coords={FooBar, FooBaz, OneMore, AnotherOne },
        ytick = data,
        enlarge x limits={value=0.5,upper},
        % using `auto` here not `upper` and/or `lower`
        % increase value to add additional space above
        % and below the bars!
        enlarge y limits={value=0.2,auto},
        legend pos=south east,
        legend image post style={scale=2.1},
        legend style={row sep=8pt, column sep=8pt}
    ]
    \addplot[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=black] coordinates 
        { (0,FooBar) (0,FooBaz) (60.0,OneMore) (40.0,AnotherOne) };
    \addplot[fill=black] coordinates 
        { (0,FooBar) (0,FooBaz) (84.5,OneMore) (15.5,AnotherOne) };
    \addplot[pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=black] coordinates 
        { (7,FooBar) (5,FooBaz) (62,OneMore) (18,AnotherOne) };
    \legend{Group 1, Group 2, Group 3}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]